# AJAX not Working in FF, works well in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I am uploading a document to the server, using PHP and AJAX with JS on button click. I collect the form data make its object append the file data and pass it via AJAX to the function upload.php. The code works completely well in Chrome but fails to give the same effect in FF. Code is attached Further. What is the possible solution to the problem ?

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploadDocument', function()
{
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileToUpload', $("#fileToUpload").prop("files")[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php',
      dataType: 'text',  
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      type: 'post',
      success: function (status){
        if(status == 'File Uploaded')
        {
          $('#listTable').load('showList.php');
        }
        else
        {}
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: any errors in the browser console or php log?

Comment: @Meiko no errors displayed and neither is the file uploaded

Comment: Please add your html to the question, I cannot see a problem with the JS code.

Comment: this is likely because of the default action of the form, you need to prevent that. pass in event to your onclick function and then use `event.preventDefault();` on the first line in the function

Comment: @Omarjmh your suggestion just did the trick ;)

Comment: Nice. Happy to help! I posted it below

Answer (score 0):

this is likely because of the default action of the form, you need to prevent that. pass in event to your onclick function and then use `event.preventDefault();` on the first line in the function